# Tool to reformat VB.Net code - specifically line breaks

Tags: vb.net, reformat

Are there any tools available for automatically formatting vb.net code - specifically for adding line breaks at a predefined line length? I'm working with a lot of code with long lines (thousands of lines), and manually reformatting it is quite time consuming. I've seen a number of tools for rearranging code into regions etc., but haven't found any that reformat with line breaks. Free would be great.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, then you can just turn Word Wrap on (Edit/Advanced/Word Wrap). Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try having VS auto-wrap your lines. The option should be in the Tools | Options | Basic | Settings | Word Wrap.

Another thing to do is go to the Edit | Advanced | Format Document menu option, which helps clear the air with not well-formed documents.

A 3rd option is to install DevExpress' Code Rush Xpress add-on, which add's very handy vertical lines for when code blocks begin and end, and also helps in refactoring code. You can get it from here: http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/. It's free, but doesn't support the Express editions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Didn't know about the auto-wrap feature. Makes it easier to read, but I'm after a permanent solution - i.e. actually insert line breaks and '_' chars. I've got DevExpress Code Rush installed and like it, and have used the ClassCleaner plugin, but there are no line break functions I've found. Resharper has the functionality I'm after, and I'm trying the trial version of it now. It looks quite good, but doesn't meet the last criteria...

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual Studio 2008 you have to use Ctrl + A + K + F for formatting your c#, vb code

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted a long time ago.  But if ever someone had the same problem, try this sub I made.  The sub will have two outputs (Textbox1 = Code with breaks, Textbox3 = a one liner code).

Create two textboxes (named Textbox1 and Textbox3) and a button (Button1)

Create a sub (name what you want) and enter this code:

```
Try
            Dim x As String = TextBox1.Text

            x = x.Replace("& """, "")
            x = x.Replace(""" _", "")
            x = x.Replace("""", "")
            x = x.Replace(vbNewLine, "")
            x = x.Replace(vbTab, "")

            While x.Contains("  ")                     '2 spaces.
                x = x.Replace("  ", " ")      'Replace with 1 space.
            End While

            TextBox3.Text = x

            Dim l As Integer = Len(x)
            Dim xlim As Integer = InputBox("Specify the maximum number of characters for each line:", "Line Max", 66)
            Dim ylim As Double = 0

            TextBox1.Text = ""

            ylim = l / xlim

            If Int(ylim) <> ylim Then
                ylim = Int(ylim) + 1
            Else
                ylim = Int(ylim)
            End If

            Dim una As String = "", huli As String = ""
            Dim mynewstring As String = ""
            Dim startin As Integer = 1
            For i = 1 To ylim
                If i = 1 Then
                    una = """"
                Else
                    una = vbTab & "& """
                End If
                If i = ylim Then
                    huli = """"
                Else
                    huli = """ _"
                End If
                mynewstring = mynewstring & una & Strings.Mid(x, startin, xlim) & huli & vbNewLine
                startin += xlim
            Next

            TextBox1.Text = mynewstring

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

P.S. I did not add the code to restore your original input.